# Does redis template support pipelining?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

Let say for example I have list A and HashMap B which contains lists with index references to List A. How can I can get the values from List A based on a certain key-value pair in HashMap B in one redis operation.

```
HashMap B:

    Key         Value
    hello            ->  2,5,6,7

List A:   p,x,y,z
    
          0,1,2,3
```

Comment: When you reference hello -> 2, you need to get `p` and hello -> 5 = x and so on?

Comment: I would have to do that in java. I would fetch the hello value in memory and then the values I need from list A. I don't want that.

Comment: Can you clearly explain what are you looking for?